# Help me function getListCategory()

Tags: php, mysql

```
function getCategoryList()
{
    global $conn;
    $result = @mysql_query("Select * From categories", $conn);
    $ret = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $ret[] = $row;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

=> output = null
Although database not null (ex: category(1, laptop, 500))
I think it wrong in $ret[] = $row;
Help me with

Comment: What does `print mysql_error();` after the query say?

Comment: Have you selected a database? Can we see the entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **`@mysql_query(`**.

Drop the **@** :

```
$result = mysql_query("Select * From categories", $conn);
```